# $\text{Hom}_k(k[x,x^{-1}],R)$ and $R^{\times}$ are bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field. Then $\text{Hom}_k(k[x,x^{-1}],R)$ and $R^{\times}$ are bijective.

Originally, I want to describe a relationship between the set of $k$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi: k[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ and the set of units $R^{\times}$. So I guess they are bijective. I defined a map $\phi:\text{Hom}_k(k[x,x^{-1}],R)\to R^\times$ by $f\mapsto f(x)$. Then this map is well-defined as $f(x)$ has inverse $f(1/x)\in R$. And this map is injective as the $k$-algebra homomoprhism $f:k[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ is completely determined by $f(x)$. The problem is I wonder this map is surjective i.e. for given $a\in R^\times$, is there a $k$-algebra homomorphism $f:k[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ such that $f(x)= a$? Or there is another relation between those sets?

Note. All rings are assumed to be commutative with unity and I assumed if $f$ is a ring homomorphism then $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$k[x,x^{-1}]\cong k[x,y]/(xy-1)$. However,

$$\text{Hom}_k(k[x,y]/(xy-1), R)\cong \{(a,b)\in R^2: ab=1\}\cong R^\times.$$

Comment: How does the first isomorphism come from? $\text{Hom}_k(k[x,y]/(xy-1),R)\simeq \{(a,b)\in R^2:ab=1\}$ You mean isomorphism as a set right?

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal property of the quotient algebra and the polynomial algebra?

Comment: I know the universal property of polynomial algebra but not quotient algebra

Comment: Given (a,b) with ab=1, invoke the universal property of the polynomial algebra to obtain a morphism $k[x,y]\to R: x\mapsto a, y \mapsto b$. Can you prove that its kernel contains (xy-1)? If so, your map descends to the quotient. This shows how to go from $R^\times$ to the algebra morphisms. Conversely, take an algebra morphism $f$ and consider $(f(x),f(y))$. Can you show that these two assignments give the desired bijection?

Comment: So basically, the map I defined above is right as a map between two sets right? Surjectivity is just defining $f(x) = a$ then the map $f$ is completely determined.